# POST Blocked even when CORS is enabled

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, cors

I have created a `SimpleCORSFilter`based on the SpringMVC guide to allow CORS:

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-by");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

The controller code for the POST and PUT request is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        value = "admin/tile/{id}"
)
public boolean saveNewTile(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    ContextEntity contextEntity = new ContextEntity("tile", id);
    //TODO: USE CUSTOM DATABASE
    contextEntityDAO.save(contextEntity);

    return true;
}

@RequestMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "admin/tile/{id}"
)
public boolean updateTile(@PathVariable("id") String id, @RequestParam(required = false) ContextAttribute[] atts) {
    ContextEntity contextEntity = contextEntityDAO.findById(id);
    contextEntity.addContextAttributes(atts);

    contextEntityDAO.save(contextEntity);
    return true;
}
```

With  AngularJS v1.3.14 I am able to do GET and PUT requests, but when I try to do a POST, Firefox notifies me that the request has been blocked since the same-origin policy...

This part works fine, for instance

```
$scope.onTestOnlyClick = function() {
  $http.put('http://localhost:8080/admin/tile/' + tile.id)
};
```

However, when I do

```
$http.post('http://localhost:8080/admin/tile/' + tile.id, contextAtts);
```

It cannot complete the request, and **both lines are in the same controller!**

This is what I see with Firebug, for some reason, when I perform a POST, Firebug only shows an OPTIONS request, there is no POST afterwards.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add controller code?

Comment: Can you check if your request performs an OPTIONS request before sending the actual request? According to the specification:

"The user agent performs a preflight request using the OPTIONS method"

http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: @sgpalit right away! ;)

Comment: @OnurAktaş how can I check that?

Comment: did you try posting to a different URL '/tile2/id

Comment: just check on firebug/chrome developer tools

Comment: @sgpalit yes, same result though...

Comment: but is CORS enabled for those preflight option requests also?

Comment: @OnurAktaş curiously enough, for the PUT method there is an OPTIONS, but when i do the POST, there is only a OPTIONS, there is no post, i am upodating the question

Comment: because the preflight is telling browser not to make the post. Check the headers in the preflight request

Comment: @charlietfl,@OnurAktaş I have updated the question with the details of the requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **Content-Type** to **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** in your filter. Tested on my local with success.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you explain in your answer the theory behind those changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this-

```
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-by");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        return;
     }
}
```